# Email Sending Feature after registration error

Tags: php, wordpress, security, email

Hello guys I am currently working on a registration page on our project Using WORDPRESS where I will send a Confirmation through Email after registration

I am using this Code.. The Code is working right and fine and I also don't see any Error, because if I use it independently without wordpress it is Working. But when I put it inside the wordpress It doesn't send the email at all like in yahoo or gmail? I don't know what is causing the error .
Can you guys give me solution for this?
Sorry for the Bad English.

```
$peremail = "blablashdjjkas@yahoo.com";
$to = "$peremail";
$subject = "Successfully Registered";
$message = "
Welcome to the Data Portal\n
Thank you very much in trusting Us
Account Detail
Username: $username
Password: $password2";
$header = "From:TITLE Subject \r\n";
$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

But when i use this code outside the wordpress it is working. Don't know what's the error.

BTW the page that I am using is already published online I don't know is there any security issues??
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wordpress is using wp_mail function for sending mail.Replace your mail function with wp_mail or you can directly use WP-Mail-SMTP plugin for sending all the mails https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/.